# add consecutive numbering to field stating in 1 Rails + Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

[current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb734.png)

I want the `topic_order` field starting from 1, currently it sorted from first to last but start anywhere, I want a migration to bulk update all the topics so it starts from 1 until n.
I could make:

```
def change
 i=1
 Topic.all.each do |topic|
  topic.update(topic_order: i)
  i += 1
 end
end
```

But is not efficient, I got hundreds of topics, Is there any way to make it better and faster? Thanks in advance

Comment: Optimizing the performance of migrations should not be a priority!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default in a migration:

```
def change
  execute "SELECT setval('products_id_seq', 1)"
  change_column :topics, :topic_order, :integer, default: -> { "nextval('topic_id_seq')" }
end
```

Hope this will help you.